# Работа с AJAX-запросом

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, fetch

Имеются следующие файлы:
router.js

```js
router.post('/database/sqlBilder', jsonParser, function (request, response) {
    if (!request.body) return response.sendStatus(400);
    sqlBilder(request.body.code, request.body.table, [request.body.login, request.body.password]);
});
```

handler.js

```js
let user = JSON.stringify({ 'code': code,
                            'table': table, 
                            'login': args[0].value, 
                            'password': args[1].value });
                                    
let response = await fetch('./database/sqlBilder', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: user,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
})

if (response.ok) {
    let text = response.json();
    console.log(text);
    alert("Запрос выполнен: " + response.status);
} else {
    alert("Ошибка HTTP: " + response.status);
}
```

sqlBilder.js

```js
query = `SELECT * FROM ${table} WHERE`;
// ...
query += ` id = '${args[0]}';`;
pool.execute(query, (err, results)=>{
  if (err) { 
      throw err;
  }
  else{
      console.log('Из базы получена запись');
      console.log(results[0].id);
  }

  return JSON.stringify({ 'id': results[0].id});
});
```

Суть в следующем: к на html страние происходит вызов AJAX-запроса, в него передаются данные, запрос поступает на обработчик, где парсится и его данные уходят в импортированную функицю, там выполняется sql-запрос к базе, который успешно сигнализирует мне о том, что получен верный id. До этого момента все работает. На сколько я понимаю, я должен не просто выполнить sql-запрос, но и вернуть его результат и разумеется данные не возвращаются и на html странице или к консоле браузера вижу `Ошибка HTTP: 500`.

Хотелось бы узнать как нужно возвращать и принимать результат этого запроса?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: твоя правка ухудшила понимание вопроса и тем не менее, причина твоего вопроса - именно незнание того как работать с callback и promise

Comment: На счёт правки, согласен, пытался убрать лишнее. С незнанием тоже согласен, но я не понимаю, что делаю не правильно, так как из того, что я читал все должно работать

Comment: не правильно вот что: код, который запустил sqlBilder никак не взаимодействует с результатом выполнения sqlBilder потому что выполнение sqlBilder асинхронно.  как исправить: изучить асинхронность https://learn.javascript.ru/async

Comment: А почему данный код должен взаимодействовать с результатом?

Comment: ты сам сказал что это нужно: "я должен не просто выполнить sql-запрос, но и вернуть его результат и разумеется данные не возвращаются"

Comment: Ну так и где тут связь? Дополнил код, но результат тотже

Comment: нет :) ты дополнил код client-side, а речь совсем не про него. в вопросе ты описываешь проблему лучше чем в комментариях :) "там выполняется sql-запрос к базе, который успешно сигнализирует мне о том, что получен верный id. До этого момента все работает. На сколько я понимаю, я должен не просто выполнить sql-запрос, но и вернуть его результат" <- у тебя запускается sqlBilder, выполняется запрос, но сервер не получает его результат, не ждёт результат запроса

Comment: Тогда вообще очень странно. Я руководствовался исходя из того, что когда код в sqlBilder выполнится результат вернется router. Однако это не происходит. Тогда соответственно вопрос: как вернуть туда результат, чтобы потом он вернулся на fetch?

Comment: в первом комментарии написан ответ на этот вопрос

Comment: Если рассматривать принятый там ответ в спецификации ES2017, то у меня это  написано, т.е. функция handler и мне это не помогло. Другие варианты, тоже не предстваляю как использовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не является до конца решением моей проблемы, но все полезнее комментариев, не объясняющих как исправить проблему.

Во первых, код в файле handler требуется изменить следующим образом:

```js
if (response.ok) {
    const text = await response.json();
    console.log('Успех:', JSON.stringify(text));
    alert("Запрос выполнен: " + response.status);
} else {
    alert("Ошибка HTTP: " + response.status);
};
```

Во вторых, в файле router внутри обработчика post дописал возврат значения в ответе:

```js
if (!request.body) return response.sendStatus(400);
console.log(request.body);
let result = sqlBilder(request.body.code, request.body.table, [request.body.login, request.body.password]);
console.log(result);
response.json(JSON.stringify({ result: result }));
```

На текущий момент я могу успешно получить результат на ajax запросе, только если сразу пропишу вместо последней строки следующие:

```js
response.json(JSON.stringify({ 'id': 1 }));
```

К сожалению пока, что не удалось получить аналогичный ответ с sqlBilder, хотя я на router объявлял ассинхронную функцию, экспериментировал с ассинхронной функцией на самом sqlBilder ...